# Submenus of Shortcuts are not displayed on Meta Stack Exchange

Tags: support, meta, google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts

I have the problem that the `Go to..`-Menü is not shown when I hit <kbd>G</kbd> on Meta Stack Exchange. On Stack Overflow all is fine.

Also "order questions by.." (<kbd>O</kbd>) is not working. It seems that all Shortcuts that provide a submenu are not displayed.

Pressing <kbd>G</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> works. That returns to Home, but Menu is not displayed.

Pressing <kbd>?</kbd> shows the `Help`-Menu.

I´m using the latest Chrome (Version 41.0.2272.76 m).

**Update**:
This problem seems to occur only on Chrome, cause on IE 11, the menu is displayed.

Comment: *Also Ctrl+B and Ctrl+I work only in question or answer posts, not in comments. If the above request is sorted out, please look into this as well.*

Comment: @ghosts_in_the_code That's a different thing entirely. Please post a separate feature request.

Comment: @AnnaLear Sorry, but I had asked some bad questions earlier on meta, and am banned from asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved!

It was only related to one of my Windows Accounts. My Home account did not have the problem. So I cleared all cookies and site data of meta.stackexchange.com and now the Menu is diplayed when I hit <kbd>G</kbd>.